# Can you store a returned value from a method in a different method as a variable?

Tags: java, scope

I'm new to java programming, and I don't understand variable scopes yet, so I'm not sure if this is possible, however:

I was trying to store:

```
return value;
```

as a variable in my main method.

I have a method called newPlayerCard() that generates a playing card for a player:

```
public static int newPlayerCard(int value) {

    Random r = new Random();

    int card = r.nextInt(12) + 1;
    int suit = r.nextInt(3) + 1;

    if (card == 1 && suit == 1) {
        System.out.println("You drew an ACE of CLUBS.");
        value = 11;
    }
    else if (card == 1 && suit == 2) {
        System.out.println("You drew an ACE of DIAMONDS.");
        value = 11;
    }
    else if (card == 1 && suit == 3) {
        System.out.println("You drew an ACE of HEARTS.");
        value = 11;
    }
    else if (card == 1 && suit == 4) {
        System.out.println("You drew an ACE of SPADES.");
        value = 11;
    }
    else if (card == 2 && suit == 1) {
        System.out.println("You drew a TWO of CLUBS.");
        value = 2;
    }
    else if (card == 2 && suit == 2) {
        System.out.println("You drew a TWO of DIAMONDS.");
        value = 2;
    }
    else if (card == 2 && suit == 3) {
        System.out.println("You drew a TWO of HEARTS.");
        value = 2;
    }
    else if (card == 2 && suit == 4) {
        System.out.println("You drew a TWO of SPADES.");
        value = 2;
    }
    else if (card == 3 && suit == 1) {
        System.out.println("You drew a THREE of CLUBS.");
        value = 3;
    }
    else if (card == 3 && suit == 2) {
        System.out.println("You drew a THREE of DIAMONDS.");
        value = 3;
    }
    else if (card == 3 && suit == 3) {
        System.out.println("You drew a THREE of HEARTS.");
        value = 3;
    }
    else if (card == 3 && suit == 4) {
        System.out.println("You drew a THREE of SPADES.");
        value = 3;
    }
    else if (card == 4 && suit == 1) {
        System.out.println("You drew a FOUR of CLUBS.");
        value = 4;
    }
    else if (card == 4 && suit == 2) {
        System.out.println("You drew a FOUR of DIAMONDS.");
        value = 4;
    }
    else if (card == 4 && suit == 3) {
        System.out.println("You drew a FOUR of HEARTS.");
        value = 4;
    }
    else if (card == 4 && suit == 4) {
        System.out.println("You drew a FOUR of SPADES.");
        value = 4;
    }
    else if (card == 5 && suit == 1) {
        System.out.println("You drew a FIVE of CLUBS.");
        value = 5;
    }
    else if (card == 5 && suit == 2) {
        System.out.println("You drew a FIVE of DIAMONDS.");
        value = 5;
    }
    else if (card == 5 && suit == 3) {
        System.out.println("You drew a FIVE of HEARTS.");
        value = 5;
    }
    else if (card == 5 && suit == 4) {
        System.out.println("You drew a FIVE of SPADES.");
        value = 5;
    }
    else if (card == 6 && suit == 1) {
        System.out.println("You drew a SIX of CLUBS.");
        value = 6;
    }
    else if (card == 6 && suit == 2) {
        System.out.println("You drew a SIX of DIAMONDS.");
        value = 6;
    }
    else if (card == 6 && suit == 3) {
        System.out.println("You drew a SIX of HEARTS.");
        value = 6;
    }
    else if (card == 6 && suit == 4) {
        System.out.println("You drew a SIX of SPADES.");
        value = 6;
    }
    else if (card == 7 && suit == 1) {
        System.out.println("You drew a SEVEN of CLUBS.");
        value = 7;
    }
    else if (card == 7 && suit == 2) {
        System.out.println("You drew a SEVEN of DIAMONDS.");
        value = 7;
    }
    else if (card == 7 && suit == 3) {
        System.out.println("You drew a SEVEN of HEARTS.");
        value = 7;
    }
    else if (card == 7 && suit == 4) {
        System.out.println("You drew a SEVEN of SPADES.");
        value = 7;
    }
    else if (card == 8 && suit == 1) {
        System.out.println("You drew a EIGHT of CLUBS.");
        value = 8;
    }
    else if (card == 8 && suit == 2) {
        System.out.println("You drew a EIGHT of DIAMONDS.");
        value = 8;
    }
    else if (card == 8 && suit == 3) {
        System.out.println("You drew a EIGHT of HEARTS.");
        value = 8;
    }
    else if (card == 8 && suit == 4) {
        System.out.println("You drew a EIGHT of SPADES.");
        value = 8;
    }
    else if (card == 9 && suit == 1) {
        System.out.println("You drew a NINE of CLUBS.");
        value = 9;
    }
    else if (card == 9 && suit == 2) {
        System.out.println("You drew a NINE of DIAMONDS.");
        value = 9;
    }
    else if (card == 9 && suit == 3) {
        System.out.println("You drew a NINE of HEARTS.");
        value = 9;
    }
    else if (card == 9 && suit == 4) {
        System.out.println("You drew a NINE of SPADES.");
        value = 9;
    }
    else if (card == 10 && suit == 1) {
        System.out.println("You drew a TEN of CLUBS.");
        value = 10;
    }
    else if (card == 10 && suit == 2) {
        System.out.println("You drew a TEN of DIAMONDS.");
        value = 10;
    }
    else if (card == 10 && suit == 3) {
        System.out.println("You drew a TEN of HEARTS.");
        value = 10;
    }
    else if (card == 10 && suit == 4) {
        System.out.println("You drew a TEN of SPADES.");
        value = 10;
    }
    else if (card == 11 && suit == 1) {
        System.out.println("You drew a JACK of CLUBS.");
        value = 11;
    }
    else if (card == 11 && suit == 2) {
        System.out.println("You drew a JACK of DIAMONDS.");
        value = 11;
    }
    else if (card == 11 && suit == 3) {
        System.out.println("You drew a JACK of HEARTS.");
        value = 11;
    }
    else if (card == 11 && suit == 4) {
        System.out.println("You drew a JACK of SPADES.");
        value = 11;
    }
    else if (card == 12 && suit == 1) {
        System.out.println("You drew a QUEEN of CLUBS.");
        value = 12;
    }
    else if (card == 12 && suit == 2) {
        System.out.println("You drew a QUEEN of DIAMONDS.");
        value = 12;
    }
    else if (card == 12 && suit == 3) {
        System.out.println("You drew a QUEEN of HEARTS.");
        value = 12;
    }
    else if (card == 12 && suit == 4) {
        System.out.println("You drew a QUEEN of SPADES.");
        value = 12;
    }
    else if (card == 13 && suit == 1) {
        System.out.println("You drew a KING of CLUBS.");
        value = 13;
    }
    else if (card == 13 && suit == 2) {
        System.out.println("You drew a KING of DIAMONDS.");
        value = 13;
    }
    else if (card == 13 && suit == 3) {
        System.out.println("You drew a KING of HEARTS.");
        value = 13;
    }
    else if (card == 13 && suit == 4) {
        System.out.println("You drew a KING of SPADES.");
        value = 13;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("ERROR: THE CARD WAS NOT RECOGNIZED");
        value = 0;
    }

    return value;

}
```

I also have my main method here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Description: Blackjack Program - Single player BlackJack vs Dealer

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
    String name = s.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter your balance: $");
    int bal = s.nextInt();

    // Declaring Suits
    final int SPADES = 0;
    final int HEARTS = 1;
    final int DIAMONDS = 2;
    final int CLUBS = 3;
    // Finished declaring suits

    // Declaring cards
    final int ACE_1 = 1;
    final int ACE_11 = 11;
    final int TWO = 2;
    final int THREE = 3;
    final int FOUR = 4;
    final int FIVE = 5;
    final int SIX = 6;
    final int SEVEN = 7;
    final int EIGHT = 8;
    final int NINE = 9;
    final int TEN = 10;
    final int JACK = 10;
    final int QUEEN = 10;
    final int KING = 10;
    // Finished declaring cards

    // Explaining the rules:
    System.out.println("\nThe rules of blackjack are simple: \n");
    System.out.println("You and the dealer are dealt two cards... Both of the player\'s cards are face up,\nwhile only one of the dealer\'s cards is face up, the other one is face down. ");
    System.out.println("You then draw cards one at a time. Each card has a value between 1 and 11. The goal\nis to get as close as possible to 21 without going over.");
    System.out.println("\nThe values are shown below: ");
    System.out.println("ACE = " +  ACE_1 + " or " + ACE_11 + "\nTWO = " + TWO + "\nTHREE = " + THREE + "\nFOUR = " + FOUR + "\nFIVE = " + FIVE + "\nSIX = " + SIX + "\nSEVEN = " + SEVEN + "\nEIGHT = " + EIGHT + "\nNINE = " + NINE + "\nTEN = " + TEN + "\nJACK = " + JACK + "\nQUEEN = " + QUEEN + "\nKING = " + KING + "\n");

    // Assigns an amount to "bet"
    System.out.print("Please enter your bet: $");
    int bet = s.nextInt();

    // Checks to see if the bet is more money than {user} has.
    while (bet > bal) {
        System.out.println("Nice try! That bet is more money than you have, try again. (Balance = $" + bal + ")");
        System.out.print("Please enter your bet: $");
        bet = s.nextInt();
        // Finishes checking the bet amount.
    }

    if (bet < bal) {
        bal -= bet;
        System.out.println("Your bet of $" + bet + " has been subracted from your account. Your new balance is $" + bal + ".");
    }


    // Creates two cards for the player
    int playerValue = 0;
    newPlayerCard(playerValue);
    newPlayerCard(playerValue);
    // Creates one card for the dealer
    newDealerCard();


}
```

Is there a way to store value, so that I can use it in my main class?
This is a blackjack game, so the value would be the total summary of the cards' values added together.
Right now I get a value of one card each time newPlayerCard(playerValue); is called. Is there a way to store the first card's value, so that I can add cards without the value being reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You method returns `value` so you can store that in your main method like this:

```
int playerCard1 = newPlayerCard(0);
```